# How to import zig module from another module?

Tags: import, build, zig

Assuming following folder structure:

```
src/
   lib.zig
   module_a/
      file_a.zig
      file_a_test.zig
   module_b/
      file_b.zig
      file_b_test.zig
   tools/
      tools.zig
      tools_test.zig
```

How should I structure my `build.zig` in order to be somehow able to use:

```
const tools = @import("tools")
```

in my two other modules: `module_a` and `module_b`?

I also want to be able to run the tests somehow, so they don't break, for example in this fassion:

```
zig test src/module_a/file_a_test.zig
```

This is NOT an application, I don't have a `main.zig` file.
I can have a `lib.zig` file though somewhere under `src` directory if it's needed.

Tried to look for a simple answer on Reddit and on StackOverflow, but couldn't find any. All the solutions use either an old `std.build.Pkg` system, or `b.addModule` but with a `main.zig` build target.

Comment: "and on this forum". FYI: StackOverflow is not a forum.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry for that, I'll correct that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so eventually I was able to figure this one out, but there could be some kind of a tutorial about this, because this was a trial and error.

So I've managed to add a main testing file to my file structure and it now looks like this:

```
src/
   lib.zig
   lib_test.zig
   module_a/
      file_a.zig
      file_a_test.zig
   module_b/
      file_b.zig
      file_b_test.zig
   tools/
      tools.zig
      tools_test.zig
```

The content of `lib_test.zig` is as follows:

```
const std = @import("std");

test {
    _ = @import("module_a/file_a_test.zig");
    _ = @import("module_b/file_b_test.zig");
    _ = @import("tools/tools_test.zig");
}

test "my custom lib test" {
    try std.testing.assert(1 == 1)
}
```

And my content of `build.zig` is like this:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.Build) void {
    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});
    const optimize = b.standardOptimizeOption(.{});

    const tools = b.addModule("tools", .{ .source_file = .{ .path = "src/tools/tools.zig" } });
    const module_a = b.addModule("module-a", .{ .source_file = .{ .path = "src/module_a/file_a.zig" } });
    const module_b = b.addModule("module-b", .{ .source_file = .{ .path = "src/module_b/file_b.zig" } });
    
    const unit_tests = b.addTest(.{
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/lib_test.zig" },
        .target = target,
        .optimize = optimize,
    });
    unit_tests.addModule("tools", tools);
    unit_tests.addModule("module-a", module_a);
    unit_tests.addModule("module-b", module_b);
    
    const run_unit_tests = b.addRunArtifact(unit_tests);

    const test_step = b.step("test", "Run unit tests");
    test_step.dependOn(&run_unit_tests.step);
}
```

So we have to create our `tools` module by addModule, and then when adding another modules to the build "namespace" we have to provide all the dependencies that those modules (i.e. `.zig` files) use, we do that by providing them to unit_tests, because unit tests are in fact "ran".

We can gather all the tests into a single file with a special test syntax.

After that to run the tests we do:

```
zig build test
```

The tests are ran every time there is a change in the code, not every time we invoke the command.

Comment: I've removed some unnecessary code pieces and adjusted the text below so that it resembles the code better.

Comment: This seems not to work when you try to import the module in another file of the project as module like @import("tools"), I get en error: error: file exists in multiple modules.